# How do I configure notification alerts on a job property?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, seq

I want to receive an email when a job completes or fails.

Comment: Google it -- first result looked promising for me... https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=send+email+sql+server+job

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/   i had gone up to second step suceesfully after that my mail is in queue it was failed to send to reciepeint mail ...

Answer (score 0):

Set up an operator under 'Operators'. Set a 'Notification' up for the job you are creating to go to an operator.  Ensure that DatabaseMail is set up or it won't be able to email anything.  Ensure that the 'SQL Server Agent' has 'Enable mail profile' set up under properties>Alert System(this is a setting that more than a few times causes things not to work).   You may have to reset the agent if you set up database mail and then enable it on the agent as the change sometime does not take till the agent is reset.  That should enable email delivery on a job.

Comment: The problem is SMTP Server is not present in my system.The mail which i send was in queue but it was failing to send to reciepient .

Comment: You can't receive an email from SQL Server without an SMTP server setup as far as I have ever seen.